# Java Parsing CSV to Array OutofBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, csv, parsing

it seems like this is a question a bit commonly asked but I just can't figure out a fix for my issue. I'm attempting to pull the data from a CSV file titled "Movies" which lists data as follows:

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
```

Up to 3952 movies. I have written the following code to parse the data into an array as follows:

```
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(moviesCSV))){
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            movies = line.split("::");  
        }        
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Which then throws the following exception:

```
3952Contender, The (2000)Drama|ThrillerException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at Assignment7.main(Assignment7.java:39)
```

Now obviously this is some sort of issue when with my loop hits my final null line, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried throwing in if statements to catch that it's on the 3952 and exit after that, but nothing seems to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

One additional question, as I feel like this is something I'm going to have an issue with later. What I'm trying to do once I have this data (and data from two other CSV files) is load these arrays to an SQL database. I need to separate the movie from the year and create a separate year column. Is there a way to do that while I'm parsing my CSV? I figured that is easier done once I already have the array created. Thanks!

Comment: Which line is 39 in `Assignment7.java`? BTW array indexes are zero-based, the third element is `array[2]`.

Comment: Errr wait a minute...you may have just answered my question. I was running a for loop after my while to print the first few items in my array to confirm that the data moved over properly and it appears that was what gave me the error. So I guess my question is now - what is the proper way to look into my array at each item?

Comment: The loop index needs to go from `0` to `array.length - 1`. Like `for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)`

Comment: What if I just want to look at the first few items? This is what I was running that gave me the error (sorry for the poor formatting):
      for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   System.out.print(movies[i]);
  }

Comment: Your starting string contains `::` two times. This means that once splitted you'll have an array with exactly 3 elements. You cannot read 5 values from an array of 3 elements.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand how to make this work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: However please don't use numbers to limit the loop. Use `i < array.length`. This way you'll never get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`